# Grab Xbox live friends list from bungie

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xbox

Hey all, I'm trying to grab and display a friends list from bungies friends list.aspx file:
https://www.bungie.net/Stats/LiveFriends.aspx
and display them in a desktop application.. VB or something

How would I be able to do this? Does it have anything to do with asp? Are there any tutorials that can show me how to grab and display information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really interested about consuming information from Xbox Live, you can apply for the XBL Community Developer program from free here: http://www.xbox.com/en-US/community/developer/

There you'll be provided with API access that will be quicker and more reliable then parsing data from the Bungie site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fetch the data (["scrape"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) it) through something like a `WebRequest`. That will give you the raw HTML or whatever it outputs.

I'm sure, without even looking, that it uses some kind of login as well, which you will have to support. I would guess that involves making a request with the credentials to some page and extract the cookie returned which you will have to pass around. The [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_Cookie) are passed around as headers.

The first thing you'll have to do is examine the HTML returned and determine how to process it to get the information you want. I would use Chrome and it's excellent developer tools for this, or another browser like Opera or Firefox with similar capabilities. This will also work for figuring out how to handle the session cookie.

Comment: Now when you say fetch it through a webrequest, you mean in vb.net?
And yeah you're right, you need to login to bungie. Are there addons to google chrome that allow me to use these developer tools?

Comment: @MJ93: Yep, WebRequest is a .NET class in System.Net-namespace. The developer tools in Chrome is available from the start under Tools -> Developer Tools (CTRL + SHIFT + J.) With Firefox you'll probably want to use Firebug (an extension) and Opera has Opera Dragonfly which is built-in too.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe 360voice can help? Haven't looked at the API enough to know if it has what you need.

http://360voice.gamerdna.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=3

Comment: The 360 voice API doesn't contain any information about a Gamertag's friend list.